# Using KendoMenu inside KendoToolbar cause issue

Tags: kendo-ui

We want a menu in toolbar but menu inside toolbar is not work as expected.Menu popup is hide behind the toolbar.We tried to fix  but we didn't get any fix for this.I there any other way to use menu in toolbar(Note: Menu should contain sub menu).Please help me resolve this issue.

**Code**

```
 <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
            <div id="toolbar"></div>
        </div>
        <script>    
         $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
                    items: [
                        { type: "button", text: "Button" },
                        { type: "button", text: "Toggle Button", togglable: true },
                        {
                            type: "splitButton",
                            text: "Insert",
                            menuButtons: [
                                { text: "Insert above", icon: "insert-n" },
                                { text: "Insert between", icon: "insert-m" },
                                { text: "Insert below", icon: "insert-s" }
                            ]
                        },
                        { type: "separator" },                        
                        {
                           template: "<ul id='dropdown' style='width:150px;' ></ul>", overflow: "never"
                        }                            
                    ]
                });

                $("#dropdown").kendoMenu({
                    dataSource: [{
                       text: "Action",
                       value: 0,
                       items: [
                        { text: "Heading 1", value: 1 },
                        { text: "Heading 2", value: 2 },
                        { text: "Heading 3", value: 3 },
                        { text: "Title", value: 4 },
                        { text: "Subtitle", value: 5 ,
                         items: [
                               { text: "Subtitle 1", value: 1 },
                               { text: "Subtitle 2", value: 2 },
                               { text: "Subtitle 3", value: 3},
                                ]}
                             ]
                    }]
                });
            });
   </script>
</div>
```

[Sample Program](http://dojo.telerik.com/EpEdi/4)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get it to work by setting resizable: false on the ToolBar(this essentially changes the overflow-y handling of the ToolBar) but you lose the overflow area capability of the ToolBar...so not really an option.

You may notice that DropDownList/ComboBox/DatePicker popups do not get cut off when present in the ToolBar...what's the difference?
The difference is that the HTML for those popups are appended to the < body > and not inside the ToolBar at all, and then just positioned appropriately by the framework as required.

So, this led me down the path of "faking" a menu construct for use in the ToolBar that uses this popup mechanism.  After fooling around with the internal kendoPopup class for a while and failing, I settled on using a Kendo ContextMenu to get as close to the functionality as possible.

Essentially, you create a ToolBar item with a template and then convert the template into a ContextMenu instead of a Menu.
Apply a bit of styling and you pretty much have a menu that doesn't get cut off in the ToolBar.

Take a look at

> http://dojo.telerik.com/iQoyo/2

where I get your menu working by setting resizable: false(with the associated down-side) and also show 2 ContextMenu implementations, 1 using < li >'s in the template and one using a simple template and a dataSource of items like your menu code.

The only problems I see are:
1. you have to click on the "menu" to get it to show as there is no hover capability built-in 
2. When you click on the "menu", it highlights the first button in the ToolBar for some reason....this does not happen in my own code so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I get the fix the issue.In toolbar overflow is set to hidden so we want set it to visible to fix the menu issue [Link To Forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-put-a-kendomenu-inside-kendotoolbar)

```
.k-toolbar{
 overflow:visible;
}
```